# Passing Activity's context (prevent memory leak)

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have a non-activity class which creates a number of views like ImageView and TextView in my activity class.

To do this, I need to pass my activity context from `activity class` to `non-activity class`. Here is the code of my `non-activity class` -

```
public class Create {
    Activity activity;

    Create(Activity act){
        activity = act;
    }
}
```

Is this a good practise? Should I use `getApplicationContext()` instead like this? What's the difference between the two methods? -

```
public class Create {
    Context context;

    public Create(Context context){
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Will there be a memory leak if I use the above methods? Which method is better? How to destroy the context after use to prevent memory leak?

Is there any advantage of declaring the `Activity/Context` as `final` or `protected` like this -

```
protected Context context;
```

or

```
final Context context;
```

Comment: There is no different between them. But if you want to display Some of the `Views` like `Progress Dialog` or `Alert Dialog` then you should required `Activity Context`. And also tell you there no memory leak by using any one method.

Comment: Depends a bit on the lifecycle of Create about which you say nothing. The whole concept seems a bit iffy.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're using your Create object. If you're using it like:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void someMethod() {
        Create mCreate = new Create(this);
        mCreate.doSomething();
    }
}
```

It'll be fine. If you do something like use an inner class that does some stuff in the background, and the activity is closed, you might end up leaking context if the inner class hasn't finished processing yet.

In the case of use of context.getapplicationcontext vs passing the activity (which is a context), the latter is better in this situation, because I'm assuming your create class is only creating views for the activity it's associated with; once the activity is finished, the lifecycle for those views is presumably over.

Answer (score 1):

Android Activity extends ContextThemeWrapper.

ContextThemeWrapper ultimatley extends Context.

So think of Context as the superclass and Activity as a subclass. For example, Context has 10 methods and Activity has the same 10 methods plus 20 other methods.

In terms of memory leaks, that all depends on how you're using it. Make sure you destroy all unused objects in onDestroy() to prevent memory leaks. See http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/hunting-your-leaks-memory-management-in-android-part-2-of-2/

I prefer the first method. That way you still get access to the other methods that Activity provides which Context might not have.

You can do this:
public class Create extends SomethingThatRequiresASuper {
    Activity activity;

```
Create(Activity act){
    this.activity = act;
super (act.getApplicationContext())
}
```

}

You can declare Context protected if you want. That just means that the scope of that object is limited.

Don't declare it final. If you do that, you won't be able to change Context later.

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be fine to past the context through. And if you develop in android framework you could directly use attribute 'mContext' in View, but this is not work in SDK.